# DQL for this SQL statement in Doctrine2 with ManyToMany relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

I've made this SQL query to get the data I need from DB and it works exactly as I want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ofreg.nombre as oficina 
  FROM nomencladores.oficina_regional AS ofreg  
  LEFT JOIN negocio.solicitud_usuario_oficina_regional AS solusofreg
    ON (ofreg.id = solusofreg.oficina_regional_id)
  JOIN nomencladores.tipo_tramite tram
    ON (tram.id = solusofreg.tipo_tramite_id)
  WHERE (tram.id = 1);
```

Since my relation will not generates any extra field on the third table then I decide to go for proper annotations on my entities, take a look:

```
class TipoTramite
{
    use IdentifierAutogeneratedEntityTrait;
    use NamedEntityTrait;
    use ActiveEntityTrait;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\OficinaRegional", inversedBy="tipoTramites", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="negocio.solicitud_usuario_oficina_regional", schema="negocio",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="oficina_regional_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tipo_tramite_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $oficinaRegionals;
}

class OficinaRegional
{
    use IdentifierAutogeneratedEntityTrait;
    use NamedEntityTrait;
    use ActiveEntityTrait;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TipoTramite", mappedBy="oficinaRegionals", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $tipoTramites;
}
```

Having those entities and supposing they are right (correct me if I'm wrong) I need to write a DQL that satisfies the above SQL code, can any give me some help writing this DQL?

I always have do it having a intermediary entity but this case is totally new for me. As and addition I know a workaround on this and will be create a `view` at DB level and write a entity just for that view with not `set` method just the `get` methods since will be a read only entity but I don't know if is the right path to go and I really like to learn how to do it using ManyToMany (in my project I have a lot of relation of this type so for sure I'll need this help later in the near future).

**UPDATE**

Ok, I'll like to keep this my track on this problem and I was doing some tests but without any helpful result, here are my tries:

**First approach**

```
public function filtrarOficinaRegionalPorTramite($tramite)
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb
        ->select('ofr.nombre AS oficinaRegional, ttr.nombre as tipoTramite')
        ->from("AppBundle:OficinaRegional", "ofr")
        ->where("ofr.activo = :activo")
        ->leftJoin("AppBundle:TipoTramite", "ttr");

    $qb->setParameter('activo', TRUE);

    if ($tramite != NULL) {
        $qb->andWhere('ttr.id = :tramite');
        $qb->setParameter('tramite', $tramite);
    }

    echo $qb->getQuery()->getSQL();
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Didn't work since the result SQL from the previous code is this one:

```
SELECT n0_.nombre AS nombre0, n1_.nombre AS nombre1 
FROM nomencladores.oficina_regional n0_ 
LEFT JOIN nomencladores.tipo_tramite n1_ 
 ON (n0_.activo = ?)
```

**Second approach**

```
public function filtrarOficinaRegionalPorTramite($tramite)
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb
        ->select('ofr.nombre AS oficinaRegional, ttr.nombre as tipoTramite')
        ->from("OficinaRegional ofr")
        ->where("ofr.activo = :activo")
        ->leftJoin('ofr.TipoTramite ttr');

    $qb->setParameter('tramite', $tramite);

    if ($tramite != NULL) {
        $qb->where('ttr.id = :tramite');
        $qb->setParameter('tramite', $tramite);
    }

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

But got this error:

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder::from(),
>   called in
>   /var/www/html/project.dev/src/AppBundle/Entity/Repository/RegionalOfficeRepository.php
>   on line 25 and defined in
>   /var/www/html/project.dev/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php
>   line 721

**Third approach**

After pass a huge amount of time trying to get things working I'm still having issues but this time I'm closer to fix them. So, here is my latest shot, with this code:

```
public function filtrarOficinaRegionalPorTramite($tramite)
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb
        ->select('ofr.nombre AS oficinaRegional, ttr.nombre as tipoTramite')
        ->distinct()
        ->from("AppBundle:OficinaRegional", "ofr")
        ->where("ofr.activo = :activo")
        ->leftJoin("ofr.tipoTramites", "ttr");

    $qb->setParameter("tramite", $tramite);

    if ($tramite != NULL) {
        $qb->andWhere("ttr.id = :tramite");
        $qb->setParameter("tramite", $tramite);
    }

    echo $qb->getQuery()->getSQL();
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

I got this SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT n0_.nombre AS nombre0,
                n1_.nombre AS nombre1
FROM nomencladores.oficina_regional n0_
  LEFT JOIN negocio.solicitud_usuario_oficina_regional n2_ ON n0_.id = n2_.tipo_tramite_id
  LEFT JOIN nomencladores.tipo_tramite n1_ ON n1_.id = n2_.oficina_regional_id
WHERE n0_.activo = ?
      AND n1_.id = ?;
```

Which is not wrong at all, but this is how the final SQL should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT n0_.nombre AS nombre0,
                n1_.nombre AS nombre1
FROM nomencladores.oficina_regional n0_
  LEFT JOIN negocio.solicitud_usuario_oficina_regional n2_ ON n0_.id = n2_.oficina_regional_id
  LEFT JOIN nomencladores.tipo_tramite n1_ ON n1_.id = n2_.tipo_tramite_id
WHERE n0_.activo = TRUE
      AND n1_.id = 1;
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your join column mappings are incorrect  for TipoTramite, try flipping them around.

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\OficinaRegional", inversedBy="tipoTramites", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="negocio.solicitud_usuario_oficina_regional", schema="negocio",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tipo_tramite_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="oficina_regional_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
```

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table

As for the question marks, those are just parameters that will be filled in later.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem and I was discovered few minutes ago and I was answer my own question but since you did it reward goes to you, thanks for the tip